# a phrase for using another battery for our vehicle

Tags: phrase-request

Is there a phrase (or idiom) for a situation in which the battery of our vehicle is finished and we need to use the battery of another vehicle in order to start our engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common term for that in British English is 'jump starting'. This is achieved using a pair of 'jump leads'.

[Jump-start](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jump-start)

Comment: We say the same thing in US English too.